# Laravel selectbox selected attribute with pivot column

Tags: php, select, serialization, laravel-4

I have a bit of a problem what i am stuck with.

I have a ManyToMany relation storing body measurements in my database and these are serialized arrays,

**My measurements table**

```
id | name   | value
1  | Height | a:61:{i:0;s:6:"150 cm";i:1;s:6:"151 cm";i:2;s:6:"152 cm";i:3;s:6:"153 cm";i:4;s:6:"154 cm";i:5;s:6:"155 cm";i:6;s:6:"156 cm";i:7;s:6:"157 cm";i:8;s:6:"158 cm";i:9;s:6:"159 cm";i:10;s:6:"160 cm";i:11;s:6:"161 cm";i:12;s:6:"162 cm";i:13;s:6:"163 cm";i:14;s:6:"164 cm";i:15;s:6:"165 cm";i:16;s:6:"166 cm";i:17;s:6:"167 cm";i:18;s:6:"168 cm";i:19;s:6:"169 cm";i:20;s:6:"170 cm";i:21;s:6:"171 cm";i:22;s:6:"172 cm";i:23;s:6:"173 cm";i:24;s:6:"174 cm";i:25;s:6:"175 cm";i:26;s:6:"176 cm";i:27;s:6:"177 cm";i:28;s:6:"178 cm";i:29;s:6:"179 cm";i:30;s:6:"180 cm";i:31;s:6:"181 cm";i:32;s:6:"182 cm";i:33;s:6:"183 cm";i:34;s:6:"184 cm";i:35;s:6:"185 cm";i:36;s:6:"186 cm";i:37;s:6:"187 cm";i:38;s:6:"188 cm";i:39;s:6:"189 cm";i:40;s:6:"190 cm";i:41;s:6:"191 cm";i:42;s:6:"192 cm";i:43;s:6:"193 cm";i:44;s:6:"194 cm";i:45;s:6:"195 cm";i:46;s:6:"196 cm";i:47;s:6:"197 cm";i:48;s:6:"198 cm";i:49;s:6:"199 cm";i:50;s:6:"200 cm";i:51;s:6:"201 cm";i:52;s:6:"202 cm";i:53;s:6:"203 cm";i:54;s:6:"204 cm";i:55;s:6:"205 cm";i:56;s:6:"206 cm";i:57;s:6:"207 cm";i:58;s:6:"208 cm";i:59;s:6:"209 cm";i:60;s:6:"210 cm";}
2  | Weight | a:76:{i:0;s:5:"35 kg";i:1;s:5:"36 kg";i:2;s:5:"37 kg";i:3;s:5:"38 kg";i:4;s:5:"39 kg";i:5;s:5:"40 kg";i:6;s:5:"41 kg";i:7;s:5:"42 kg";i:8;s:5:"43 kg";i:9;s:5:"44 kg";i:10;s:5:"45 kg";i:11;s:5:"46 kg";i:12;s:5:"47 kg";i:13;s:5:"48 kg";i:14;s:5:"49 kg";i:15;s:5:"50 kg";i:16;s:5:"51 kg";i:17;s:5:"52 kg";i:18;s:5:"53 kg";i:19;s:5:"54 kg";i:20;s:5:"55 kg";i:21;s:5:"56 kg";i:22;s:5:"57 kg";i:23;s:5:"58 kg";i:24;s:5:"59 kg";i:25;s:5:"60 kg";i:26;s:5:"61 kg";i:27;s:5:"62 kg";i:28;s:5:"63 kg";i:29;s:5:"64 kg";i:30;s:5:"65 kg";i:31;s:5:"66 kg";i:32;s:5:"67 kg";i:33;s:5:"68 kg";i:34;s:5:"69 kg";i:35;s:5:"70 kg";i:36;s:5:"71 kg";i:37;s:5:"72 kg";i:38;s:5:"73 kg";i:39;s:5:"74 kg";i:40;s:5:"75 kg";i:41;s:5:"76 kg";i:42;s:5:"77 kg";i:43;s:5:"78 kg";i:44;s:5:"79 kg";i:45;s:5:"80 kg";i:46;s:5:"81 kg";i:47;s:5:"82 kg";i:48;s:5:"83 kg";i:49;s:5:"84 kg";i:50;s:5:"85 kg";i:51;s:5:"86 kg";i:52;s:5:"87 kg";i:53;s:5:"88 kg";i:54;s:5:"89 kg";i:55;s:5:"90 kg";i:56;s:5:"91 kg";i:57;s:5:"92 kg";i:58;s:5:"93 kg";i:59;s:5:"94 kg";i:60;s:5:"95 kg";i:61;s:5:"96 kg";i:62;s:5:"97 kg";i:63;s:5:"98 kg";i:64;s:5:"99 kg";i:65;s:6:"100 kg";i:66;s:6:"101 kg";i:67;s:6:"102 kg";i:68;s:6:"103 kg";i:69;s:6:"104 kg";i:70;s:6:"105 kg";i:71;s:6:"106 kg";i:72;s:6:"107 kg";i:73;s:6:"108 kg";i:74;s:6:"109 kg";i:75;s:6:"110 kg";}
```

**Relation table users_measurements**

```
user_id | measurement_id   | value
1       | 1                | 160 cm
1       | 2                | 50 kg
```

**measurements controller**

```
public function measurements()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $measurements = Measurement::all();

        $this->layout->title = "Measurements";
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user::settings/measurements')
                                 ->with('user', $user)
                                 ->with('measurements', $measurements);
    }
```

And my view, i loop through the results to generate a form

**View**

```
{{ Form::open(array('id' => 'ajax-', 'class' => 'ui fluid form segment')) }}
    <div class="two fields">
        @foreach($measurements as $measurement)
            <div class="field">
              <label for="{{ $measurement->id }}">{{ $measurement->name }}</label>
              <select name="{{ $measurement->id  }}" id="{{ $measurement->id }}" class="form-select">
              <option value="">{{ $measurement->name  }} kiválasztása</option>
                  @foreach(unserialize($measurement->value) as $value)
                    <option value="{{ $value }}" >{{ $value }}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
        @endforeach  
   </div>

{{ Form::submit('Módosítások mentése', array('class' => 'ui tiny orange button')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

So i am really stuck how to solve to add the actual selected attribute to my selectbox

I tried a few things.

In my controller i store the logged in user in the `$user` variable.

I tried

```
$user-measurement->lists('value');
```

This gave back the following result

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1095) "a:61:{i:0;s:6:"150 cm";i:1;s:6:"151 cm";i:2;s:6:"152 cm";i:3;s:6:"153 cm";i:4;s:6:"154 cm";i:5;s:6:"155 cm";i:6;s:6:"156 cm";i:7;s:6:"157 cm";i:8;s:6:"158 cm";i:9;s:6:"159 cm";i:10;s:6:"160 cm";i:11;s:6:"161 cm";i:12;s:6:"162 cm";i:13;s:6:"163 cm";i:14;s:6:"164 cm";i:15;s:6:"165 cm";i:16;s:6:"166 cm";i:17;s:6:"167 cm";i:18;s:6:"168 cm";i:19;s:6:"169 cm";i:20;s:6:"170 cm";i:21;s:6:"171 cm";i:22;s:6:"172 cm";i:23;s:6:"173 cm";i:24;s:6:"174 cm";i:25;s:6:"175 cm";i:26;s:6:"176 cm";i:27;s:6:"177 cm";i:28;s:6:"178 cm";i:29;s:6:"179 cm";i:30;s:6:"180 cm";i:31;s:6:"181 cm";i:32;s:6:"182 cm";i:33;s:6:"183 cm";i:34;s:6:"184 cm";i:35;s:6:"185 cm";i:36;s:6:"186 cm";i:37;s:6:"187 cm";i:38;s:6:"188 cm";i:39;s:6:"189 cm";i:40;s:6:"190 cm";i:41;s:6:"191 cm";i:42;s:6:"192 cm";i:43;s:6:"193 cm";i:44;s:6:"194 cm";i:45;s:6:"195 cm";i:46;s:6:"196 cm";i:47;s:6:"197 cm";i:48;s:6:"198 cm";i:49;s:6:"199 cm";i:50;s:6:"200 cm";i:51;s:6:"201 cm";i:52;s:6:"202 cm";i:53;s:6:"203 cm";i:54;s:6:"204 cm";i:55;s:6:"205 cm";i:56;s:6:"206 cm";i:57;s:6:"207 cm";i:58;s:6:"208 cm";i:59;s:6:"209 cm";i:60;s:6:"210 cm";}" [1]=> string(1300) "a:76:{i:0;s:5:"35 kg";i:1;s:5:"36 kg";i:2;s:5:"37 kg";i:3;s:5:"38 kg";i:4;s:5:"39 kg";i:5;s:5:"40 kg";i:6;s:5:"41 kg";i:7;s:5:"42 kg";i:8;s:5:"43 kg";i:9;s:5:"44 kg";i:10;s:5:"45 kg";i:11;s:5:"46 kg";i:12;s:5:"47 kg";i:13;s:5:"48 kg";i:14;s:5:"49 kg";i:15;s:5:"50 kg";i:16;s:5:"51 kg";i:17;s:5:"52 kg";i:18;s:5:"53 kg";i:19;s:5:"54 kg";i:20;s:5:"55 kg";i:21;s:5:"56 kg";i:22;s:5:"57 kg";i:23;s:5:"58 kg";i:24;s:5:"59 kg";i:25;s:5:"60 kg";i:26;s:5:"61 kg";i:27;s:5:"62 kg";i:28;s:5:"63 kg";i:29;s:5:"64 kg";i:30;s:5:"65 kg";i:31;s:5:"66 kg";i:32;s:5:"67 kg";i:33;s:5:"68 kg";i:34;s:5:"69 kg";i:35;s:5:"70 kg";i:36;s:5:"71 kg";i:37;s:5:"72 kg";i:38;s:5:"73 kg";i:39;s:5:"74 kg";i:40;s:5:"75 kg";i:41;s:5:"76 kg";i:42;s:5:"77 kg";i:43;s:5:"78 kg";i:44;s:5:"79 kg";i:45;s:5:"80 kg";i:46;s:5:"81 kg";i:47;s:5:"82 kg";i:48;s:5:"83 kg";i:49;s:5:"84 kg";i:50;s:5:"85 kg";i:51;s:5:"86 kg";i:52;s:5:"87 kg";i:53;s:5:"88 kg";i:54;s:5:"89 kg";i:55;s:5:"90 kg";i:56;s:5:"91 kg";i:57;s:5:"92 kg";i:58;s:5:"93 kg";i:59;s:5:"94 kg";i:60;s:5:"95 kg";i:61;s:5:"96 kg";i:62;s:5:"97 kg";i:63;s:5:"98 kg";i:64;s:5:"99 kg";i:65;s:6:"100 kg";i:66;s:6:"101 kg";i:67;s:6:"102 kg";i:68;s:6:"103 kg";i:69;s:6:"104 kg";i:70;s:6:"105 kg";i:71;s:6:"106 kg";i:72;s:6:"107 kg";i:73;s:6:"108 kg";i:74;s:6:"109 kg";i:75;s:6:"110 kg";}" }
```

I tried so many methods to process this data to return the actual users pivot column values, but no luck

If anybody could help me out would really make my day, or any hint please

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay if anybody else needs help with this i wrote a function in my **user model**

```
public function selectedMeasurement()
    {
        foreach ($this->measurement as $measurement) 
        {
            $selected[] = $measurement->pivot->value;
        }

        if (!empty($selected)) 
        {
            return $selected;
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

And in my view

```
{{ Form::open(array('id' => 'ajax-', 'class' => 'ui fluid form segment')) }}
    <div class="two fields">
        @foreach($measurements as $measurement)
            <div class="field">
              <label for="{{ $measurement->id }}">{{ $measurement->name }}</label>
              <select name="{{ $measurement->id  }}" id="{{ $measurement->id }}" class="form-select">
              <option value="">{{ $measurement->name  }} kiválasztása</option>
                  @foreach(unserialize($measurement->value) as $value)
                    <option value="{{ $value }}" {{ in_array($value, $user->selectedMeasurement()) ? 'selected="selected"' : "" }} >{{ $value }}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
        @endforeach  
   </div>

{{ Form::submit('Módosítások mentése', array('class' => 'ui tiny orange button')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::select($measurement->id, unserialize($measurement->value), $user->value, array("id" => $measurement->id, "class" => "form-select") ) }}
```

Try this.

Comment: thanks for your help and effort writhing your answer but this did not solved my problem

Comment: what is wrong in the above code. Tell me the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and that is how I solved it.

I added this in my controller, in the edit method and passed it into the view:

```
$selectedTags = $product->tags()->pluck('tag_id')->toArray();
```

And in the view file I added it like this:

```
<option value="{{$row->id}}"{!! in_array($row->id, $selectedTags) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' !!}>{{$row->name}}</option>
```